# How to fetch nested map fields in a Firestore Document

Tags: javascript, firebase, react-native, google-cloud-firestore, expo

I've been using Firestore in Firebase and for now i've been able to extract the whole document but I can't extract one of the variables (for example, latitude):
[image: Firestore Document Screenshot]

[image: Document Output Example]

And here is my code that works (JavaScript with React Native and Expo):

```
let cityRef = db.collection('pacientes').doc('paciente-test');
let getDoc = cityRef.get()
.then(doc => {
if (!doc.exists) {
  console.log('No such document!');
} else {
  console.log(doc.id, " => ", doc.data());
}
})
.catch(err => {
console.log('Error getting document', err);
})
```

I tried many things with doc.data(), like doc.data().latitude (with an undefined output) but whenever I change it, it doesn't compile. I've seen other solutions around but they don't work for me for some reason.
If you think I've missed any info that could be more helpful let me know

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your document contains a single field called "safeArea" which has nested properties.  You have to reference those nested properties as object properties in the "safeArea" object, like this:

```
doc.data().safeArea.latitude
```